# Failure to reconnect after De-authentication from Cisco AP Wifi

Tags: ios, networking, wifi

Apologizing in advance, I am no 802.11 expert and this is a long winded question...

I am working on an iOS voip client, we use the Cocoaasyncsocket library for our TCP/UDP connections. The app/iDevice is allowed to roam in/out of wifi coverage (for the purposes of this discussion we will assume the app is using wifi only... no cellular connection). We have the appropriate plist settings for backgroundmode (voip, audio) as well as requiring persistent wifi.

We are having a problem that seems particular to Cisco AP's. With the client app in the foreground and roaming out and in of wifi range, we noticed that eventually the iOS device will eventually not automatically rejoin the network. After a great deal of debug the failure to rejoin was noted to have nothing to do with the app. The failure to re-join can ultimately be reproduced by forcing the AP (via config) to deauthenticate the iDevice three times. After the 1st and 2nd deauthentications, the iDevice readily automatically re-joins. But after the 3rd time, iOS does not automatically rejoin the network.

The network will be rejoined if, for example, the iOS email app is put in the foreground.

We were curious if any other VOIP type apps suffered this problem, and ran an experiment with running FaceTime and Skype on the iOS device.

Skype behaved much like our voip app, after the 3rd deauth the connection was lost. Trying to initiate another call resulted in a message to the effect of "must have an internet connection to make a call".

FaceTime did disconnect on the 3rd deauth and failed to automatically rejoin... however, we were able to re-initiate another FaceTime call which caused iOS to rejoin the network and make the call.

We would like to emulate the FaceTime behavior, but so far do not understand what we should be doing differently. To the best of our knowledge, we are properly closing the open sockets when we get disconnected. Is anyone familiar with this issue and have some insight to offer?

Comment: What errors(errno) do you get on your socket code when it its disconnected? Always worth using socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` in case your socket address is left in use somehow: Again what errors do you get. If you do not use `SCNetworkReachability`, it might be worth using to check the internet connection before use as it may initiate some low level check on the WiFi.

Comment: Since I don't have the failing router on hand, I will have to revisit your question about the error number. We are setting SO_REUSEADDR and we are also qualifying the the connection with SCNetworkReachability. One unfounded theory as to how FaceTime is able to reconnect is that apple apps may be able to use a wifi/ssid scan api which is not available to developers.

Comment: For looking for SSIDs, I believe the two main interfaces are CaptiveNetwork (which is now deprecated but fully re-instated in iOS9, so still usable) and NEHotspotHelper (requires permission from Apple to use). Not sure either of these would initiate a scan though. The other thing you could try is setting the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key in your Info.plist file. You probably have this already, but it might force a scan when your app launches if it is set. It seems designed to prevent WiFi being closed, but might force a check if no WiFi is connnected when you run.